# testing in Laravel 5.5 : Class env does not exist

Tags: laravel, testing, integration-testing

i am starting tests in laravel

i created a ".env.testing" file with this

```
APP_NAME=myApp
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://myApp.localhost

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite_testing
```

i added this in the "connections" part of config/database.php file

```
...
'sqlite_testing' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix'   => '',
],
...
```

in the phpunit.xml file, i added :

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite_testing" />
```

and i created a UserTest feature :

```
class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        Artisan::call('db:seed');
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
    }


    public function testCanAccessUserSpace()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)
            ->get('/home');


        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

But when i run the tests, i have this :

```
ReflectionException: Class env does not exist
```

What's wrong with my config ?

thanks

Comment: We would need a stack trace to figure out where something went wrong. I would initially guess that you should call `parent::tearDown()` after doing your own stuff so that the parent hasn't destroyed any application instances when you're trying the Artisan call.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! As you said, `parent::tearDown();` must  be called after `Artisan::call('migrate:reset');`

Answer (score 48):

I had same error while running the phpunit:

> ReflectionException: Class env does not exist

Here was another problem, I've installed package *telescope* and phpunit tried to load it while testing:

```
ReflectionException: Class env does not exist
/var/www/html/mat2/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php:263
/var/www/html/mat2/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Telescope.php:222
```

and so on.
I've added to phpunit.xml:

```
<env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
```

Afterwards, tests are running fine.
So, it may be package testing related error.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, set TELESCOPE_ENABLED to false doesn't solve my problem. I have to issue

> php artisan config:clear

I use Laravel 7.

Comment: Worked like a charm in my case.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `php artisan test --env=testing`, add `TELESCOPE_ENABLED=false` to your `.env.testing` file and run `php artisan config:cache --env=testing`.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this exception is thrown for a variety of reasons. In your case the issue is with the tearDown function, in specific order of operations within this function. You should call the parent tearDown at the bottom. So this:

```
public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
}
```

Should be refactored as follows:

```
public function tearDown()
{
    Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

I suspect the reason is that the app instance gets destroyed inside `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`. here is the code from Laravel 5.5:

```
if ($this->app) {
    foreach ($this->beforeApplicationDestroyedCallbacks as $callback) {
        call_user_func($callback);
    }

    $this->app->flush();

    $this->app = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This error can be caused by telescope being turned on in a unit testing environment.

I change the default behaviour of telescope to be off and explicitly turn it on in my `.env` file.

You can change the default to false for telescope by updating your `config/telescope.php` file.

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Telescope Master Switch
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option may be used to disable all Telescope watchers regardless
    | of their individual configuration, which simply provides a single
    | and convenient way to enable or disable Telescope data storage.
    |
    */

    'enabled' => env('TELESCOPE_ENABLED', false), // Change from true to false here.
```

You will then have to set: `TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true` in your .env file. This will ensure that you don't have it accidentally turned on in environments you don't want such as production and unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late for a reply, but the below line in phpunit.xml solved the issue.

```
<server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue and found issue in config folder > constants file
I was wrote "asset('/')" function in config file, we can't write such functions in config.

Hope this answer will help someone who stuck like this errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename `.env.testing` to `.env`, you already set `APP_ENV` to `testing`  so there is no need to change your `.env` to `.env.testing`

**EDIT:**

Also try to update your dependencies with `composer update` and try again, it's not a usual bug, so it's something related to your setup of testing environment

Comment: .env file is my development environment whith a mysql database so i can't replace it

Comment: Try running these methods in this order: `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan clear:route`, `php artisan clear:config`, `php artisan optimize`

Comment: id did : `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan optimize`

i have the same message : ReflectionException: Class env does not exist

Comment: I installed fresh laravel 5.5 app and my tests are running through, not giving me any error

Comment: I realized `php artisan optimize` was the cause of this error for me in Laravel 8, maybe I should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my config/services.php file, my error was calling the route() method in array. I just removed the method and back to works.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer in more detail by sharing some code.

Comment: I was using a helper function inside de config classes, thats broke my code, its a generic error that happen for me, there is no code to share.

Comment: same for me, In my case it was beucase I was using route() inside fortify.php configuration file

Comment: Thats good ! A simple stupid mistake hahahah

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8, don't try to use laravel global helper function or Facade after `TestCase::tearDown`:

```php
class MyTestCase extends TestCase
{
  public function tearDown(): void
  {
    parent::tearDown();
    // This will case this exception:  Target class [env] does not exist
    echo app()->environment();
  }
}
```

Instead, move method **BEFORE** `parent::tearDown`, it will work:

```
public function tearDown(): void
{
   echo app()->environment();
   parent::tearDown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, my problem was something else entirely... I was trying to use config or env values in my unit test's "tearDown" method *after* calling the parent's implementation, which destroyed the application!

So this obviously does not work:

```
protected function tearDown(): void {
    parent::tearDown();
    $environment = App::environment();
    ...
}
```

but this will...

```
protected function tearDown(): void {
    $environment = App::environment();
    ...
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**For laravel version 8 change app()->environment() to env('ENV_NAME') like**

```
env('SMS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT')
```

Example:

> Previous: **app()->environment() === 'production'**

> New Format should be **env('DEV_ENV') === 'production')**

**Note:** *Don't forget to add DEV_ENV=production in your .env file*